# Identifying obfuscation/encription method

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have following string:

```
soqDi22c2_A-eY4ahWKJV6GAYgmuJBZ3poNNEixha1lOhXxxoucRuuzmcyDD_9ZYp_ECXRPbrBf6issNn23CUDJrh_A5L3Y5dHhB0o_U5Oq_j4rDCXOJ4Q==
```

It's a query parameter generated by form on a page. (This is done server-side in ASP.net) We are able to submit this form programatically and get the string we need (it just leads to a detail page of an object [realworld parcel/building, publicly accessible]) and redirect our user to it. However I would like to know, if there is a way to decrypt/deobfuscate this string to know what it contains and if we could possibly just generate these without going through the form (it's a multi step form).

The string also has some sort of expiration, so I sadly cannot provide a link to the result page, as it would stop working after like 10 minutes or so.

It feels a bit like it's base64, but after trying to run it through `base64 -d`, it says it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely base64 with + and / replaced with - and _ to make it more browser-friendly.
Though even if it's base64-**encoded**, it may just be a completely random key. You won't nessesarily be able to decode it to something readable.

Comment: Ah didn't think about the replacement. I suspect it contains some data, but as you say, it can just be a random key.
I have dealt with stuff like this my self, when we had a long JSON, which we needed to have in URL. What we did was gzip->base64->urlencode, I was hoping this was the same case, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't figure out what the data is supposed to be, but maybe you can find something I didn't. It looks random to me. https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9_%5C%5C-%3D',false)To_Hex('None',0/disabled)To_Binary('None',8)Frequency_distribution(false,true)&input=c29xRGkyMmMyX0EtZVk0YWhXS0pWNkdBWWdtdUpCWjNwb05ORWl4aGExbE9oWHh4b3VjUnV1em1jeUREXzlaWXBfRUNYUlBickJmNmlzc05uMjNDVURKcmhfQTVMM1k1ZEhoQjBvX1U1T3FfajRyRENYT0o0UT09

Comment: Nah, that looks random. Maybe it just is and internal ID, so there's nothing we can do about it. Thanks a lot for the effort tho!
I'll mark your answer as accepted as there is probably nothing more to do with this.